# Drop down menu populated by jquery ajax not shown after submit to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a complete newbie in terms of jquery ajax and was so happy to found a code for my chain select drop down menu on the internet. 
The good thing is that the drop down is getting populated correctly and when I confirm it is getting saved in the mysql database, I see the saved value from the first drop down  but I don't see the value in the second drop down menu anymore. I have no idea why this happens and would therefore greatly appreciate it, if someone you look into below code and let me know what I am doing wrong:

Jquery for the pre-populated drop down:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#category").change(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#type").html(data);
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

And the part of the drop down menu:

```
<?php include "select.class.php"; ?>    

                      <div class="control-group">
                   <label class="control-label">Kunde</label>
                        <div class="controls">

                   <select tabindex="1"  id="category" class="span5" name="kundennummer">
                           <?php $query = mysql_query("SELECT Kundennummer FROM auftrag WHERE Auftragsnummer=".$eventid);    
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$id = $row['Kundennummer'];
echo mysql_error();
                           echo $opt->ShowCategory();

                            echo '<script>';
echo 'document.formname1.kundennummer.value='.$id.';';
echo '</script>';
 ?>
                         </select>

                        </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Veranstaltungsort</label>
                        <div class="controls">

                   <select tabindex="1"  id="type" class="span5" name="veranstaltungsort">

                            <?php
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT Veranstaltungsort FROM auftrag WHERE Auftragsnummer=".$eventid);    
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$ort = $row['Veranstaltungsort'];
echo mysql_error();


                            echo '<script>';
echo 'document.formname1.veranstaltungsort.value="'.$ort.'";';
echo '</script>';?>
                         </select>
```

Comment: do you mind copying the compiled html and javascript in [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) so can take a better look at the code?

Comment: I will have a try. Never done that. And there are several different php files depending on each other. So might be difficult to use JSFiddle

Comment: yes i understand,been there before,the thing is that; we need to the jquery properly,regardless to the php part,just run any random option and then copy the compiled html

Comment: console it in firebug and check it what you post to the server.. I have the doubt on this {id:id} your value is stored in id and you pass the field name as id

Comment: Can you post the `data` that is returned in your `$.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){...}`

Comment: but you wouldn't have access to the database then. So I have left out all the php parts and only included the HTML and jquery on it.http://jsfiddle.net/v9tcM/

Comment: from what i checked,id variable is only capturing the selected value of the first select,so to confirm,you want to post both value ti database??

Comment: @AhmedAli That id is only used to populate the second select

Comment: @SandraGrassl the markup in your fiddle is not the same as in your PHP (i.e. no name attribute on inputs), can you post the markup as it's being generated?

Comment: The values are inserted into the database correctly. And the first drop down is populated with the selected value after the confirmation. Only the second drop down is not displaying the value although I do show selected value in the   echo '<script>';
echo 'document.formname1.veranstaltungsort.value="'.$ort.'";';
echo '</script>';?>

Comment: @koala_dev : `var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');` this is only for the first select `id="category` am i correct?

Comment: @SandraGrassl : try to `echo $id` and `echo $ort` and display the out please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v9tcM/1/

Comment: @SandraGrassl : one last request,with samples- can you describe the processing of the selects? i mean when you select an option from the first select,what is expected to happen?

Comment: In what format it the `data` that you are returning and adding to the second select? `$("select#type").html(data);` Is it html options - `<option value=""></option>` or is it some other format?

Comment: and my last request: post the final HTML after PHP has run, that is, the complete select with the options generated and the script tags as they are echoed

Comment: @Ali based on my selection from the first drop down the second drop down gets populated. Both values are then saved in the database. The values saved should then be returned as selected in the drop down. The first one is working fine. The second option is not getting displayed.

Comment: Can you post what the second option html looks like, AFTER it gets populated? there could be a syntax error that is preventing it from being posted/inserted in your database properly.

Comment: based on your code code,i assume on second scenario is showing `wait...` ? correct??

Comment: @koala_dev: This is the result of the second drop down in the html after the php has run through: <select id="type" class="span5" name="veranstaltungsort" tabindex="1" disabled="disabled">
<script>
document.formname1.veranstaltungsort.value="VA: ING DiBa";
</script>
</select>

Comment: There is your problem - `disabled="disabled"`. Disable elements are not posted. You have to remove the `disabled="disabled"` before the form is submitted.

Comment: @SandraGrassl no `<option>`s?

Comment: sorry guys got it working now. I inserted: echo '<option value="'.$ort.'">'.$ort.'</option>';

Comment: Congrats for figuring that out,the thing is,we needed more info and code in order to better understanding :)

Comment: Well I think I deserve some credit no? :p and may I ask why are you presenting the values that were just submitted again in a form?

Comment: good question @koala_dev, this could cause some damage or inconstancy on the database i believe.

Comment: @AhmedAli as my mother would say - "its like pulling teeth". over an hour to get the `<option>` code out.

Comment: @Sean : you're lucky to have such a wise mum ;) and it is pulling teeth indeed.